# Android: int h=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() return wrong value on my acer tablet

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a app that allows you to drag shapes around.  It works fine on smart phones, but not on my Acer a500 tablet

When I get the height by calling

```
ih=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-25;
```

I get a value thats only 1/3 of what it should be, thus I can only drag the sahpes 1/3 the way down.  If the tablet is horizonatl it goes 1/2 way down.

Why is this methed returning the wrong values for the height on my tablet??

```
public class cPlay extends  cBase  implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //      setContentView(R.layout.play);


        int w=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()-25;
        int h=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-25;

        BallView ballView=new BallView(this,w,h);
        setContentView(ballView);
   } // end function

   public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();

       } // end function

} // end class
```

Comment: what values do you get, what do you expect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
  int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
  int Width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods getWidth() and getHeight() are deprecated in Display.
Try to use DisplayMetrics.
Also you might want to get the size of your view's container by calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() after onMeasure() was called to get more precise size of your view.